# Tomcat 8 redirecting after HTML form submit

Tags: java, html, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have an HTML form in an admin interface for my webapp.  It's a large form so I've omitted the input elements, but the pertinent tags look like:

```
<form id="config" action="updateConfig" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Save configuration" name="submit1"/>
...
...
</form>
```

This is hosted at http://servername:port/webapp/admin and clicking the button should submit the form to http://servername:port/webapp/admin/updateConfig
and refresh the page (i.e. reload http://servername:port/webapp/admin)

This works perfectly with Tomcat 7 in all browser combinations.

However, with Tomcat 8 it behaves differently.  When using Firefox, Chrome and Safari, the form submit works, but the browser then tries to redirect to http://servername:port/webapp/admin/updateConfig.  It works as before with IE/Edge

I've searched the Tomcat 8 documentation, but can't find any obvious changes which could lead to this behaviour.  Any help would be most appreciated.

A bug report can be found here: https://github.com/Reading-eScience-Centre/edal-java/issues/54#issuecomment-212529593 which gives further details about how the redirection is happening.

Comment: Can you do a protocol trace of what's happening and post that? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some experimentation I've figured this out.  The issue was that the webapp was sending a blank redirect:

```
response.sendRedirect("")
```

In Tomcat <=7, that was redirecting to http://servername:port/webapp/admin (i.e. the page which submitted the post), whereas in Tomcat 8 it was being treated differently.  From the headers it seems that Tomcat 7 was intercepting the redirect and explicitly inserting the full URL into the "Location" header, whereas Tomcat 8 just sends an empty location which gets interpreted differently on different browsers.

The solution therefore was to change the redirect to:

```
response.sendRedirect("./")
```

which works with both Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8.